# Google Cloud Appengine Flex websockets support

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

Is there a way for deploying websockets server on Google Cloud Appengine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. There is an [open ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348) for this feature, it's been open since 2009. There is maybe some light at the end of the tunnel though, as they've started to make an alpha version of this available.

Comment: Wanted to give an update that Google just released beta support for web sockets! https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity

Answer (score 0):

There was a way for doing it for non secure sockets only(ws), but seems they are no longer support it. Lately they also removed samples from docs in [this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/commit/18210b3bd741da95b42fbea884922ef4c7cd57fe).

Not sure if there are plans for supporting websockets based solutions on appengine in future, so for deploying such a thing on Google Cloud you probably should use Compute Engine, atleast that's the way I go.